# js form validation radio

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to do Step by Step form, at some step in "tab" i've only radio buttons, I would like to make unable to go further until 1 of them won't be picked i've code like this:

```
var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

function showTab(n) {
    // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    x[n].style.display = "block";
    // ... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
    if (n > 0) {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
        document.getElementById('submBtn').style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('submBtn').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('submBtn').style.display = "inline";

    } else {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").InnerHTML = "Next";
    }
    // ... and run a function that displays the correct step indicator:
    fixStepIndicator(n)
}

   function validateForm() {
    // This function deals with validation of the form fields
    var x, y, i, valid = true;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");

    // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        // If a field is empty...
        if (y[i].value == "" || getElementsByTagName("selector").prop('checked', true)) {
            // add an "invalid" class to the field:
            y[i].className += " invalid";
            // and set the current valid status to false:
            valid = false;
        }
    }
    // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
    if (valid) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
    }
    return valid; // return the valid status
}
```

radio button's name is "selector", i've tried already to call them by tag name, by type, by class, by id, tried to check if it was picked by function prop(), and by ckeck status by **name**`.checked == true` and it doesn't work ;/ any sugestions ? :)

Comment: What is `currentTab`, and where is it defined? You're not passing it into the function...

Comment: i've updated Code :)